# Create bulk database entries efficiently?

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an `Activty` object for a large (300+ at a time) list of `Inquiry` objects.  I have a single `ModelForm` which is being posted back, and I need to create seperate instances, and attach them to my `Inquiry` via a `GenericForeignKey`.  Let's get to some code:

**models.py:**

```
class InquiryEntry(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    entry = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Inquiry(models.Model):
    entries = models.ManyToManyField('InquiryEntry')
    # And many more fields.
    def add_entry(self, obj):
        entry = self.entries.create(entry=obj)
        self.save()
        return entry

class Activity(models.Model):  
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                  
    due_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    ## And many more fields.
```

**views.py:**

```
def bulk_create_activities(request):
    activity_form = ActivityForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        activity_form = ActivityForm(request.POST)
        if activity_form.is_valid():    
            pks = [int(x) for x in request.POST.get('pks', '').split(',')]
            for inquiry in Inquiry.objects.filter(pk__in=pks):
                instance = ActivityForm(request.POST).save()
                inquiry.add_entry(instance)     
                inquiry.save()
```

What I am looking for is a way to insert these into the database, preferably in one pass so that the request can be processed faster.  I prefer not to drop to the database level as this application is deployed across multiple database vendors, but if that is the only way to proceed, so be it (examples for MySQL and Postgres would be awesome).

---

**Note:** I know that there is a [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) in the development version, but that is out of the question until there is a stable release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try simply enclosing your `for` in a transaction construct? Commit-on-success transactions can get you massive speed ups because entries are concretely written to disk at once in bulk, so the DBMS doesn't have to stop for fsync() after each item.

Implementing transactions in recent versions of django is snappy, check out
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but didn't change performance very much.  On 5-10 Activities, it had about a 5% speed increase.  On 100, a 10% speed decrease.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you may need to [drop to DB-API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) and use cursor.executemany(). See [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to get some hints (including for different db systems) by looking at the sql django generates for some sample data. running your server in debug mode all queries are logged. you can also inspect them via

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://people.iola.dk/olau/python/bulkops.py

It provides insert_many and update_many functions which execute a single query. As noted by the author you will have to do some manual bookkeeping in python for pks in many to many relationships, but once you have them worked out, you can simply execute couple of insert_many's on `Inquiry` and `InquiryEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make your bulk action any more efficient, but if an `Inquiry` doesn't need to be responded to instantaneously based on the data submitted (I'm assuming based on model name), this sounds like the perfect job for a task queue like Celery.

The user will get a super fast response, and your celery workers can crunch on it at their leisure. When 1.4 is stable, check out in_bulk :)

I'd also be interested in a database agnostic rock solid method but depending on your situation this might be an acceptable solution.

Will be watching answers here...